# Paginating grouped results in ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, group-by, will-paginate

In this application, a `User` has many `Status`es, accessible through `User#statuses`. Now, we're grouping the results by week to display in our view. However, we're also paginating the results using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). The problem is that it's paginating the statuses and not the weeks, making it so the different weeks are split across different pages.

I guess, at its' most basic level, I'm asking how paginate Hash keys using will_paginate.